# Google Colab Upload error, how can you fix it? (Cannot read property '_uploadFiles' of undefined)

Tags: upload, google-colaboratory

my problem is that I always get the following error when I operate the following code.Strange thing is that, when i set the epochs to 0 the error dosnt show up and I can upload with no problems. Thanks for the Help!

I have already tried anabling third party cockies, which did not help. The strange thing is, that the upload works, if I set the training epochs to 0.
Sometimes the error is google.colab._files is undefined.

I have already tried to use Chrome and Firefox.

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(training_images, training_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

training_images = training_images.reshape(60000, 28, 28, 1)
training_images = training_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images.reshape(10000, 28, 28, 1)
test_images = test_images / 255.0
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1)),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
```

])

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(training_images,training_labels, epochs=1)
classes = model.predict(test_images)
predicted_classes = np.argmax(classes, axis=1)
print(classes[0])
print(test_labels[0])

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(training_images, training_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(test_images[0], cmap='Greys_r')
import numpy as np
from google.colab import files
from keras.preprocessing import image
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys(): 
  path = '/content/' + fn
  img = cv2.imread(path) 

img = cv2.resize(img,(28,28))
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
x = image.img_to_array(img, dtype=np.float32)
print("top left pixel value:", x[0,0])
if x[0,0] > 250:
# white background
print("needs to be inverted!")
x -= 255
x *= -1
x = x / 255.0
x = x.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)
plt.imshow(img, cmap='Greys_r')
plt.show()  


classes = model.predict(x)
plt.bar(range(10), classes[0])
plt.show()
print("prediction: class", np.argmax(classes[0]))
```

TypeError: Cannot read property '_uploadFiles' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that it works if you use 2 cells one for the neural network and one for the upload feature.